# VBA putting special character in string

Tags: excel, vba

```
Range("E2").Formula = "=" & column1name & "2" & "" | "" & column2name  & "2"
```

I am trying to make formula in VBA. I want to set `E2 =( A2 | B2)` . I already used function to convert column A into variable `column1name` already. So VBA will read it as A. but I am getting error that highlight my `"|"` and saying

> invalid character.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Though solved, something in the back of my head tells me you can clean up your code a lot. Though not sure, but when you say: *"I already used function to convert column A into variable column1name"*, just to return `A` or `B` it just sounds like .... too complicated =).

Comment: Hi JvdV , i is due to sometimes my columns index will change, so I need to let it find the name instead of index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Range("E2").Formula = "=" & column1name & "2 | " & column2name & "2"
```

will return

```
=A2 | B2
```

---

// Edit according comments

```
Range("E2").Formula = "=" & column1name & "2 & ""|"" & " & column2name & "2"
```

will output

```
=A2 & "|" & B2
```

Comment: Hi PEH, I tried this code and getting application defined or object defined error . I am not sure what this error is

Comment: because `=A2 | B2` is not a valid formula. What do you expect the formula to do?

Comment: ```=A2 & "|" & B2``` this is my code in excel, I am trying to put "|" character in middle of  A and B to make it separate.

Comment: @Gunhanwei fyi in addition to the valid solution above you might be interested in an alternative via `Join()` :-)

Answer (score 2):

If your intent is to join A2 and B2 cell through formula using PIPE (|) character then you can try below code.

`Range("E2").Formula = "=" & column1name & "2&""|""&" & column2name & "2"`

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative via `Join()`**

In order not to loose a clear view over multiple quotation-mark sequences,
I'd suggest to separate into tinier parts as follows:

```
    Const PIPE As String = """|"""         ' pipe character with quotation-marks
    Sheet1.Range("E2").Formula = _
         "=" & Join(Array(column1name & "2", PIPE, column2name & "2"), "&")
```

Comment: Uh, no offence but I think this is even more non-intuitive to read than a normal string concatenation. Still +1 for showing an alternative way.